# .NET Build events xcopy application settings.settings

Tags: c#, application-settings, post-build-event

I am trying to add these lines to the application's Build Events

```
xcopy debug.settings settings.settings
```

In order to acees the debug.settings as Default, but I am getting a **exited with code 4** error when compiling. I have read code 4 would probably mean that it cannot find the specified files. But how would I reference debug.settings?

I have this file as part of my application's properties:

[image]

I got this idea from a stackoverflow question: [.NET different application settings for development and release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432580/net-different-application-settings-for-development-and-release) This would be a followup question based on its answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely because `xcopy` cannot find the source and destination paths for the settings files. Try updating them to the fully qualified path (i.e. `C:\SomeFolder\MyProject\debug.settings`).

Also, check out the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc771254(v=ws.11)) when in doubt (or looking for what error codes mean).

As an aside, if you are simply looking for a way to change values in an app.config or web.config based on your build configuration, take a look at [SlowCheetah](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.SlowCheetah-XMLTransforms).

Comment: Thanks, SlowCheetah was the way to go. Cracked my head a bit since I'd never used transforms. But the final sintax was simple. On answering my original question, I had to cd to the Properties directory and use copy instead of xcopy. This managed to copy and replace the file but the file would not get compiled. So I was heading nowhere.

Comment: Glad to hear you got this worked out. SlowCheetah is awesome and has saved me a lot of time fussing with config files.