# wpf use splash.png only in release

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2015, splash-screen

in my wpf project I added `splash.png` image to Resources and when the application run, works perfectly...

My question is: it's possible use the `splash.png` only in Release and not in Debug?

thanks in advance

Comment: probably.  Can you post the code that displays the splash.png?  You might be able to wrap that part in an "if not in debug mode" check and go from there.

Comment: thanks @sous2817 , but is 'automatic' using a wpf form: if find the splash.png or jpg it uses.. no code to do this

Comment: i know that you want to do something slightly different, but perhaps you can modify some ideas from this link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739412/wpf-splashscreen-how-to-make-splashscreen-showing-longer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to manually edit the MSBuild script file as suggested here:

[Debug-only classes and resources in visual studio - is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093214/debug-only-classes-and-resources-in-visual-studio-is-it-possible)

Right-click on the project in the Solution Explorer in Visual Studio and choose "Open Folder in File Explorer" and then open up and edit the .csproj file in a text editor such as Notepad. I am afraid Visual Studio provides no GUI that lets you do this though.

Comment: thanks I edited .csproj like this: ```<SplashScreen Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' " Include="Resources\splash.png" />```